# Vaadin Button action and MessageBox with 2 actions to do

Tags: java, button, calendar, vaadin, messagebox

I have created a remove Button who delete the data inside my database and in my calendar. But I want to use MessageBox to be sure this is not a wrong choice. But I can't add 2 actions in my MessageBox.WithYesButton(), So Have you any idea how I can do it ?
Here my code :

```
remove.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                for (CalendaringItem calendaringItem : calendaringList.getCalendarings()) {
                    MessageBox.createQuestion().withMessage("Do you want to delete this event ?").withYesButton(()
                            -> calendaringItem.delete(calendaringItem, name.getValue())).withNoButton().open();
                    //calendar.removeEvent(e);
                }
                window.close();
            }
        });
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MessageBox.createQuestion()
           .withMessage("Do you want to delete this event ?")
           .withYesButton( () -> {
               calendaringItem.delete(calendaringItem, name.getValue());
               //action
               //action2 ...
           })
           .withNoButton().open();
```

Whats more, you dont have to declare new ClickListener. You can simply do that:

```
remove.addClickListener(event -> {
    actionAfterButtonClick();
});
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you a lot, I didn' think about that ! Shame on me :)